# Wordpress / CCTM - Get custom fields from metabox by ID

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, meta-boxes

Using CCTM (Custom Content Type Manager) I've created 4 metaboxes (whose IDs are el_one_conf, el_two_conf and so on) each one with two custom fields (el_one_type, el_one_cont; el_two_type, el_two_cont).

I would like to process the various fields via getting an array of fields in a metabox by metabox's ID.

I tried using:

```
$fields=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'el_one_conf',TRUE);
```

But printing with print_r doesn't return anything.

I know that I could call the single field value using get_post_meta but I'd like to know if there's anyway I can get all the fields of a metabox inside an array so I can work via foreach loops.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're using will only ever retrieve a single custom field value.

To retrieve all of them for a given post you can use [`$fields = get_post_custom( $post_id )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) and then access each field value from the resulting array like this: `$fields['el_one_type']` though depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve this might not be much more helpful.

As far as I'm aware there is no built in way to limit the result by meta box, you would have to access the database directly. That's assuming the meta box IDs are even stored in there which they very well might not be.

Answer (score 0):

changing this:

```
$fields=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'el_one_conf',TRUE);
```

to this:

```
$fields=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'el_one_conf',FALSE);
```

will return an array. you can then print_r